# Printing attachments to the selected printer in outlook 2007 / 2010

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, printing, microsoft-outlook-2007

I want to print attachments to the selected printer using outlook 2007 or 2010. However, in the dialog box for printer options it says that the attachments will go to the default printer. Is there a way to direct the message and attachments to a selected printer without having to go in and set the default printer each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Automatic print switcher](http://automatic-printer-switcher.software.informer.com/2.1/download/).Programs will be listed in the APS software, right click on program which need to be mapped with printer and click okay.

Comment: Thanks. There's no innate way to do this in windows 7?

Comment: @James: sorry to say that, there is no such options available in windows 7.Only thing you can do from windows 7 is, you can set multiple default printer for different network.